# Return data of 4 tab separated fields per line

Tags: python, formatting

I have a list of lists that has the format:

```
l=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
```

After I call a function I return this list but I want to return something like:

```
1    2    3    4
5    6    7    8
9    10   11   12
```

As a beginner of Python, I am curios about whether this kind of return type is possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def f(a_list):
    return "\n".join(["\t".join([str(s) for s in line]) for line in a_list])
```